# hide asp label text before submitting on server

Tags: asp.net, label, validation

The problem looks very simple but it giving me pain
i am making  a login page manually which checks for user email and password from linq. on login page there is an asp label which shows the error msg based on query result like "user not exist" or "user is inactive" etc. there are asp required field validators on both text boxes.
the problem is if user first attempt get unsuccessful and message get displayed on lable, it do't go away unless user get successfully loged in. i want the text back as lable1.text="" on submit button but it can't as its a server side control and the text box validators do't let it go if empty. do i have to use java script?

Comment: Did you try to disable view state for the label?

Comment: Is your login posting back to itself on you are redirecting after login is successful?

Comment: @AmiramKorach after you said i tried but no use. is't it same as making visible=false? and if so how will enable it again? m sorry m new at asp

Comment: @tcoder yes it will return with a value from database and using that i am directing user to next page. if like no value returns from it, the label will show the appropriate msg.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do here would be to clear the messages in javascript, as you thought.

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" OnClientClick="ClearLableText" runat="server" />
```

And updated javascript, per your comment:

```
function ClearLableText() { var element = document.getElementById("<% this.lblMessage.ClientID %>"); element.innerHTML = ""; }
```

Comment: that is tried first. as this is button event, how do i pass the label id to javascript function and make its value null? i tried the same way as we do for html elements but it keep giving exception at function call or return null in java script. here is my function call and javascript: onclick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="ClearLableText('<% this.lblMessage.ClientId %>');"      function ClearLableText(elementId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.value = "";
}

Comment: this JavaScript option should work. Try `var label =  document.getElementById(<%= lblMessage.ClientId %>)` from your function instead of passing it

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your comment.  It's a little more tightly-coupled than what you originally wrote, but I'm assuming this is something that is fairly specific and won't be reused many places. (Edit: tcoder and I were thinking the same thing)

Comment: not working :( the variable showing null as value. i.e its not getting the element

Comment: Can you look at the source and copy the element and script here?

Comment: here is javascript    function ClearLableText() {
    var element = document.getElementById("<% this.lblMessage.ClientId %>");
    element.innerHTML = "";
}    here is label and button code    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
      Text=""></asp:Label>        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" 
      Text="Login" onclick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="ClearLableText()" class="login-but" value="Logga in"></asp:Button>

Comment: here is code behind            protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager();
            int loginStatus = loginManager.Login(userEmail.Text, userPassword.Text, ckbRememberMe.Checked);
            switch (loginStatus)
            {
                case 0:
                    Response.Redirect("~/Category.aspx");
                    break;
                default:
                    lblMessage.Text = "Wrong Email and Password";
                    break;
            }

Comment: I made a small change and then the message began clearing properly.  In your javascript, update "<%= this.lblMessage.ClientId %>" to "<%= this.lblMessage.ClientID %>" (uppercase "ID").

Comment: it keep giving me null in var on function call :(

Comment: Could you provide the generated source of these specific bits of code, as displayed in the browser?  Right click > View Source, firebug or something similar can provide the generated source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMessageLabel.Text = ""; //or .Visible = false;
}

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //By this time, page_load had already executed and the Message Label cleared 
   MyMessageLabel.Text = "new result from server";

   if(validResult)
     //RedirectToWhere();
   else
     //StayOnPage();
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the required field validators will prevent a postback while the field is blank, and the message will remain.  The logic above will never fire, because it relies on a postback.

Comment: thanks for help. this what i initially have. but once button is pressed and login failed, lable get the error text. i want it gone when text field validators checks the required field  BEFORE sending it to server or reloading page. just like asp validators error msgs